# BindingAdapter LiveData first value always null

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-binding-adapter

I'm trying to handle a `LiveData` value (`profilePicture: Bitmap`) within a `BindingAdapter` function but the first value is always **null**. The binding adapter is a `ViewSwitcher` with `ProgressBar` and `ImageView`.

Getting profile picture from firebase like this:

```
    val downloadPictureResult = MutableLiveData<Bitmap>()
    // ...
   fun downloadProfilePic(): LiveData<Bitmap?> {
        val imageRef = storage.getReference("images/$uid/profile/profile_picture.jpg")
        imageRef.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                //...
                downloadPictureResult.value =  responseBitmap
                //...
            } else {
                downloadPictureResult.value = null
                Log.d(TAG, task.exception?.localizedMessage)
            }
        }
        return downloadPictureResult;
    }
```

Because the first value is **null** and the second the expected **bitmap object**, the `view.showNext()`is called two times. But it's more important for me to understand why the firstvalue is **null** because the `setProfilePicture` method will have some more logic.

BindingAdapter looks like this.

```
fun setProfilePicture(view: ViewSwitcher, profilePicture: Bitmap?) {
 Log.d("PPSS", profilePicture.toString())
    val imageView: ImageView = view[1] as ImageView
    imageView.setImageDrawable(view.context.getDrawable(R.drawable.account_circle_24dp))

    profilePicture.let { picture ->
        if (picture != null) {
            val rounded = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(view.resources, picture)
            rounded.isCircular = true
            imageView.setImageDrawable(rounded)
            view.showNext()
        } else {
            view.showNext()
        }
    }
```

> Log:

```
2019-04-13 17:53:01.658 11158-11158/... D/PPSS: null
2019-04-13 17:53:02.891 11158-11158/... D/PPSS: android.graphics.Bitmap@8b6ecb8
```

Comment: Can you provide your binding code of ***xml*** and how you setup that?

Comment: Hi, that's how I'm binding to ViewSwitcher
`<ViewSwitcher android:profilePicture="@{vm.profilePicture}">`
Corrosponsing ViewModel 
 `val profilePicture: LiveData<Bitmap?> = StorageService.downloadProfilePic()
`

Answer (score 5):

When you define a `LiveData`, its initial value will be null even when its type is not nullable:

```
val downloadPictureResult = MutableLiveData<Bitmap>()
// Here, downloadPictureResult.value is null
```

In your case, the value of the `LiveData` returned by `downloadProfilePic()` will be null until the picture is downloaded, which will happen asynchronously inside the callback `addOnCompleteListener`:

```
fun downloadProfilePic(): LiveData<Bitmap?> {
    ...
    imageRef.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        ...
        // This happens asynchronously, likely after downloadProfilePic()
        // has already returned
        downloadPictureResult.value =  responseBitmap
        ...
    }

    return downloadPictureResult;
}
```

That's why the first value that gets passed to your adapter is null, because `downloadPictureResult.value` is still null at the time when `downloadPictureResult` is returned by `downloadProfilePic()` for the first time.

Answer (score 2):

Let's understand it **step by step** about how `LiveData` works in your case *(In generally)*:

1. Your method `downloadProfilePic()` returns `LiveData` of **nullable `Bitmap`** as return type. Method contains *asynchronous code* of `addOnCompleteListener` meaning that it's execution would be happen even after `LiveData` value has been returned.

Here:

```
fun downloadProfilePic(): LiveData<Bitmap?> {
    val imageRef = storage.getReference("images/$uid/profile/profile_picture.jpg")
    imageRef.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            //...
            downloadPictureResult.value =  responseBitmap
            //...
        } else {
            downloadPictureResult.value = null
            Log.d(TAG, task.exception?.localizedMessage)
        }
    }
    return downloadPictureResult;
}
```

2. You're returning `downloadPictureResult` as result of method which is initialized globally as `val downloadPictureResult = MutableLiveData<Bitmap>()` mutable livedata, so that we can modify it afterwards. And that happens inside callback of `addOnCompleteListener`.
3. Now presumably, when your view `(Activity/Fragment)` gets loaded and hence you've added your live data from `ViewModel` as **DataBinding** it gets initial value whatever is there in `LiveData` and then observes it further.
4. So here, you've initialized `LiveData` with **null value** of `Bitmap` during this code `val downloadPictureResult = MutableLiveData<Bitmap>()` it returns **null value** for very first time.
5. And then callback happens from `addOnCompleteListener` method and value is assigned livedata as `downloadPictureResult.value =  responseBitmap` or **null** eventually if error.

> That's why there are two calls for `LiveData` in your `BindingAdapter` method `setProfilePicture()`.

Note: *Simple hack you could do if you don't want two callback is making your callback synchronous instead of asynchronous.*

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers have told you, the first value will be always null. However, you can get the value when it's ready using an observer and then unsubscribe from it when you have your image.

```
val pic = downloadProfilePic()
pic.observe(owner, object : Observer<BitMap?> {
    override fun onChanged(b: BitMap?){
        if(b != null){
            setProfilePicture(yourView, b)
            pic.removeObserver(this)
        }
    }
})
```